# Loading quoted numbers into snowflake table from CSV with COPY TO <TABLE>

Tags: csv, import, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a problem with loading CSV data into snowflake table. Fields are wrapped in double quote marks and hence there is problem with importing them into table.

I know that COPY TO  has CSV specific option FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"'but it's not working at all.

Here are some pices of table definition and copy command:

```
CREATE TABLE ...
(
GamePlayId NUMBER NOT NULL,
etc...
....);


COPY INTO ...
     FROM ...csv.gz'
FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE = CSV 
               STRIP_NULL_VALUES = TRUE 
               FIELD_DELIMITER = ',' 
               SKIP_HEADER = 1  
               error_on_column_count_mismatch=false 
               FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"'
              )
ON_ERROR = "ABORT_STATEMENT"
;
```

Csv file looks like this:

```
"3922000","14733370","57256","2","3","2","2","2019-05-23 14:14:44",",00000000",",00000000",",00000000",",00000000","1000,00000000","1000,00000000","1317,50400000","1166,50000000",",00000000",",00000000",",00000000",",00000000",",00000000",",00000000",",00000000",",00000000",",00000000",",00000000",",00000000",",00000000",",00000000",",00000000",",00000000",",00000000"
```

I get an error

```
'''Numeric value '"3922000"' is not recognized '''
```

I'm pretty sure it's because NUMBER value is interpreted as string when snowflake is reading "" marks, but since I use

```
FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"'
```

it shouldn't even be there... Does anyone have some solution to this?

Comment: Typically, numeric and date fields are not quoted like this.  The purpose of quoting a field is to allow field delimiters or record delimiters to be contained within a field, so there shouldn't be a reason to do that.  Can you export the file so that numeric and datetime fields are not quoted?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something is incorrect with your file?  I was just able to run the following without issue.

```
1. create the test table:
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE 
    dbNameHere.schemaNameHere.stacko_58322339 (
    num1    NUMBER,  
    num2    NUMBER, 
    num3    NUMBER);

2. create test file, contents as follows 
1,2,3
"3922000","14733370","57256"
3,"2",1
4,5,"6"

3. create stage and put file in stage 

4. run the following copy command
COPY INTO dbNameHere.schemaNameHere.STACKO_58322339
     FROM @stageNameHere/stacko_58322339.csv.gz
FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE = CSV 
               STRIP_NULL_VALUES = TRUE 
               FIELD_DELIMITER = ',' 
               SKIP_HEADER = 0  
               ERROR_ON_COLUMN_COUNT_MISMATCH=FALSE 
               FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"'
              )
ON_ERROR = "CONTINUE";

4. results 
+-----------------------------------------------------+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------------------+-----------------------+-------------------------+
| file                                                | status | rows_parsed | rows_loaded | error_limit | errors_seen | first_error | first_error_line | first_error_character | first_error_column_name |
|-----------------------------------------------------+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------------------+-----------------------+-------------------------|
| stageNameHere/stacko_58322339.csv.gz | LOADED |           4 |           4 |           4 |           0 | NULL        |             NULL |                  NULL | NULL                    |
+-----------------------------------------------------+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+------------------+-----------------------+-------------------------+
1 Row(s) produced. Time Elapsed: 2.436s

5. view the records
>SELECT * FROM dbNameHere.schemaNameHere.stacko_58322339;
+---------+----------+-------+                                                  
|    NUM1 |     NUM2 |  NUM3 |
|---------+----------+-------|
|       1 |        2 |     3 |
| 3922000 | 14733370 | 57256 |
|       3 |        2 |     1 |
|       4 |        5 |     6 |
+---------+----------+-------+
```

Can you try with a similar test as this?

EDIT:  A quick look at your data shows many of your numeric fields appear to start with commas, so something definitely amiss with the data.

Comment: at a guess it's a "float" in a country with , as the decimal place

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the input except that it has a non-US/UK decimal comma for the floats.  Change to decimal point, and the data loads without problems.  It is pretty unusual not to support decimal comma, as that is one of the alternatives in the ISO standard for numbers :O

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your numbers are European formatted `,` decimal place, and `.` thousands, reading the [numeric formating](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql-format-models.html) help, it seems Snowflake does not support this as input. I'd open a feature request.

But if you read the column in as `text` then use [REPLACE](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/replace.html) like

```
SELECT '100,1234'::text as A
    ,REPLACE(A,',','.') as B
    ,TRY_TO_DECIMAL(b, 20,10 ) as C;
```

gives:

```
A         B         C
100,1234  100.1234  100.1234000000
```

safer would be to strip placeholders first like

```
SELECT '1.100,1234'::text as A
  ,REPLACE(A,'.') as B
  ,REPLACE(B,',','.') as C
  ,TRY_TO_DECIMAL(C, 20,10 ) as D;
```